# how to cut out stroke of a circle and color the segments like this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I am very new to illustrator. I want to cutout a stroke of a circle (fill color is turned off) using another object and then color the segments like the below steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand your circle stroke (so that it becomes a path) by going to **Object → Expand** and only choose **Stroke**

[image: Expand Panel]

You can now use the *Shape Builder Tool* or *Pathfinder* to break up the shape.

---

Pathfinder (**Window → Pathfinder** or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>);

Select all and click on **Minus Front**

[image: Minus Front in Pathfinder]

---

Shape Builder* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>);

Select all and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+*Click*+*Drag* on the areas you want to remove from your shape

[image: GIF showing Alt+Click+Drag process]

---

Now color your shapes and apply shadows how you'd like

[image: colors and shadows]

---

<sub>*Shape Builder can be a better option when dealing with very complex shapes, as pathfinder won't usually perform well. In your case, Pathfinder is very suitable (as it is very simple).</sub>

Comment: All things worked well except coloring different segments. At first, I have to ungroup the circle after cutting out the arrows, only then segments can be colored with different colors. If not, same colors will be applied to all the segments. Anyway my main question was answered correctly and I will accept your answer. Thanks to other user who replied.

Answer (score 1):

Open the pathfinder > select all > click the ’substract’ icon. Done!

[image: pathfinder palette]